# Empty screen in material design app in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating a list dynamically. Here is the html for the static version of the app

```
<div class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row-picture">
            <img class="circle" src="http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-thumb-4972069-200-pfgvuffbxtqsqdduzxzvszms.jpeg" alt="icon">
        </div>
        <div class="row-content">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">bla</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">bla</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-separator"></div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row-picture">
            <img class="circle" src="http://lorempixel.com/56/56/people/6" alt="icon">
        </div>
        <div class="row-content">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Tile with another avatar</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-separator"></div>

        <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row-picture">
            <img class="circle" src="http://lorempixel.com/56/56/people/6" alt="icon">
        </div>
        <div class="row-content">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Tile with another avatar</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The above one works absolutely fine. But the problem is arising when I try to generate the list dynamically
Here is my code for index.html

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/material.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>


            <div class="list-group-item">

                 <div class="app">
                  </div>

             </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.js

```
var names = ["one", "two", "thre", "four"];
var phones = ["90000 00000", "911111 000000", "90000 11111", "80000 80808"];
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){

    add(names[i], phones[i]);

}


function add(name, phone){

   var listItem = '<div class="row-picture">' +
    '<img class="circle" src="http://"bla">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="row-content">' +
    '<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">' + name + '</h4>' +
    '<p class="list-group-item-text">' + phone + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="list-group-separator"></div>'; // Use ; here instead of +

$('.app').prepend(listItem);
}
```

Sad part is there is no console error. And jquery is loading $('.app').append("hi") is appending fine. And when watched the debugger the for loop executes properly, with the values getting changed. Debugger has shown that append is also getting executed. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: which part is not working properly?

Comment: I am getting an empty screen where I am supposedly should get a list view

Comment: When are you getting empty screen? You said that its appending fine.

Comment: In console, it is appending fine. But I am unable to see any list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this! Its working

```js
var names = ["one", "two", "thre", "four"];
var phones = ["90000 00000", "911111 000000", "90000 11111", "80000 80808"];
for(var i=0;i<phones.length;i++){

    add(names[i], phones[i]);

}


function add(name, phone){

   var listItem = '<div class="row-picture">' +
    '<img class="circle" src="http://"bla">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="row-content">' +
    '<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">' + name + '</h4>' +
    '<p class="list-group-item-text">' + phone + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="list-group-separator"></div>'; // Use ; here instead of +

$('.app').prepend(listItem);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="list-group-item">

                 <div class="app">
                  </div>

             </div>
```